# Polymer iron-list grid not resizing in neon-animated-pages

Tags: polymer

I have `<iron-list>` with `grid` mode encapsulated by `<neon-animated-pages>` and somehow neon-pages ruin its ability to adapt to screen size and rearrange items. I tried changing position of neon pages to relative and so on. Nothing helped. Thanks in advance.
Here is the code

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
    <app-route
               route="{{route}}"
               pattern="/games/:subject"
               data="{{router}}"
               tail="{{subroute}}">
    </app-route>
    <neon-animated-pages selected="0" id="pages">   
        <games-subjects-module item="{{item}}"></games-subjects-module>
        <games-subject-module item="{{item}}"></games-subject-module>
    </neon-animated-pages>
```

And here is `<games-subjects-module>` where i have my `iron-list`

```
<template>
    <style is="custom-style">
        paper-card{
            width: 200px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 20px;
            --paper-card-header-image:{
                height: 250px;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <iron-list id="list" items="{{subjects}}" as="subject" selection-enabled selected-item="{{item}}" grid> 
        <template>
            <div>
                <a href="/games/{{subject.val.name}}">
                    <paper-card elevation="1">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            {{subject.val.name}}
                        </div>
                    </paper-card>
                </a>
            </div>
        </template>
    </iron-list>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you post your code also

Comment: I have the same problem, <iron-list> with grid attribute nested somewhere in the <neon-animated-pages> does not work, even with the example code from the element catalog